# sharing a storage class across namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-efs, kubernetes-pvc

I've been reading through docs and can't find a clear answer on how to do this.

I have an AWS EFS claim and a storage class which i have applied. I have a PV and PVC that are in a namespace and can see the storage class, which i assume is cluster wide.

If i try to apply the same PV and PVC manifests to a different namespace i get an error that the storage class is not found.

If i then delete these i get the following warning:

```
warning: deleting cluster-scoped resources, not scoped to the provided namespace
persistentvolume "efs-pv" deleted
```

This is really confusing.

How would i share this efs storage between different namespaces? do i need to make changes to the PV and PVC (at the moment i already have persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain), and what do i apply to which namespace? what is cluster wide and what is namespace scoped?

Answer (score 2):

Presumed you can do `aws efs describe-file-systems` to see your EFS is correctly configured and you have the `FileSystemId` ready for mount.

You have also installed the AWS EFS CSI driver and all driver pods are running with no issue.

For StorageClass you only create **once** for each type.

For PersistentVolume you only create **once** for each mount point (static).

In case of simultaneous access from **different** namespaces, you create one PersistentVolumeClaim in each namespace that referred the same StorageClass.

```
...
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: my-efs-sc    <--- This name MUST be referred across PVC/PC
provisioner: efs.csi.aws.com    <--- MUST have EFS CSI driver installed

...
kind: PersistentVolume
spec:
  storageClassName: my-efs-sc    <--- Have you verify the name?
  ...
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany    <--- MUST use this mode
  ...

kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  ...
  namespace: my-namespace-A    <--- namespace scope
spec:
  storageClassName: my-efs-sc    <--- Have you verify the name?
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany    <--- MUST use this mode
  ...

kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  ...
  namespace: my-namespace-B    <--- namespace scope
spec:
  storageClassName: my-efs-sc    <--- Have you verify the name?
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany    <--- MUST use this mode
  ...
```

Check the PVC/PV status with kubectl to ensure all are bound correctly.

Comment: Hey, yes this is exactly what ive done ive applied the namespace when applying the manifest so im actually applying the same pvc manfiest just to different namespaces, with ReadWriteMany accessMode

Comment: If you still getting `storage class is not found`, the `warning...` that you get as per described in your question, your driver setup and/or your pod/pvc/pv are not correct. Suggest you start with a static provision in a single namespace to ensure everything works as expected, then move on to multi-namespaces.

Comment: The key here is the provisioner and its static provisioning setup.

Answer (score 1):

PV‘s are non namespaced and PVC‘s are namespaced. So you can not easy use the same PV (where the data is) in two different namespaces, because it‘s not possible to have to claims for one PV.

Comment: so would i need to have more than one storage class? how would i do this?